# Add links to each tags in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my project there is a list of posts and each post is associated with multiple tags(many to many association between tags and posts).In post show page list of tags will be displayed.How do i create a link to each tag which links to the posts associated with that tags?

**Posts/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <strong>Author:</strong>
  <%= @post.user.username %>
  <p>
    <strong>Content:</strong>
    <%= @post.content %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <% if @post.tags.present? %>
        <strong>Tags:</strong>
        <%= @post.tags.map{|t| link_to t.tag_name, **   }.join(", ").html_safe %>

       <% end %></p>
```

There is a join table where I can access that?
how can I direct the links to the posts associated with that tag?.

Comment: one tag has multiple posts , and you want with that tag it should show all posts?

Comment: so far as i understand, it should be done something like , on click on tag it should redirects to another page where we should show all posts title, and on click that title we can redirect it that particular posts/show page

Comment: Yes. Thats what i need

Comment: sure we can do that.

Comment: do I have to include post index path with t.posts as actual parameter

Comment: lets try the given answer, let me know for further guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `posts/show.html.erb`

```
<% if @post.tags.present? %>
   <strong>Tags:</strong>
    <%= @post.tags.map{|t| link_to t.tag_name, get_all_posts_of_tag_path(id: tag.id)   }.join(", ").html_safe %>
   <% end %>
<% end %></p>
```

create a routes for `get_all_posts_of_tag_path`

```
get '/tag/id', to: 'tags#get_posts', as: get_all_posts_of_tag
```

and create a `get_posts` action

```
def get_posts
  tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  @posts = tag.posts
end
```

in `get_posts.html.erb`

```
<%if @posts.present? %>
  <%@posts.each do |post|%>
    <%= link_tag post.title, post_path(id: post.id)%>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: I think you have some copy-paste errors in `posts/show.html.erb`: you have `erb` tags inside `erb` tags. Also, you're testing `if @post.tags.present?` after already having tested it. Might just be a carry over from the OP.

Comment: Where to add the path for the link? can't get your answer

Comment: @ jvillian, thanks for your suggestion, it was just some syntax errors , while i copy and paste,i have fixed those syntax errors

Comment: @Aarthi, please have a look answer again, it was messed up with some syntax errors, now i have changed it, you will get to know where to add link.i think its clear straight.

Comment: feel free to accept/upvote answer,if it helped you @Aarthi

Comment: Added as answer

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<p>
  <% if @post.tags.present? %>
    <strong>Tags:</strong>
    <%= safe_join(@post.tags.map { |t| link_to t.tag_name, tag_path(t) }, ", ".html_safe) %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Where `tag_path(t)` links to the `show` action of `TagsController`, and you need to build `tags/show.html.erb`